# How to get current file position after reading one line from a file?

Tags: c#

In C# how to read a line and after reading how to get the file current position?

```
FileStream fStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
 var reader = new StreamReader(fStream);
 while (!reader.EndOfStream)
 {

 string line = reader.ReadLine();

 }
```

After reading a line if I call fStream.Position , it gives position value as entire file length only.

Comment: It gives the position as the length of the entire file because you're reading to the end of the file with `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`.  Also, reads are buffered.  I would expect it to always read multiples of 1024 bytes by default.

Comment: Try with reader.BaseStream.Position

Comment: It looks like StreamReader reads 4K at a time from the stream it's wrapping. Is your input smaller than 4K? You'd need the position from StreamReader, not the file stream. and I don't think it's available. It's likely not as simple as the number of characters read either as the byte position since StreamReader will decode multibyte sequences if supported by your encoding.

Comment: The `FileStream.Position` is updated when the `1K` buffer  is filled. So it will just report multiples of 1024. You're probably not using the right tool if you need this information. You could *manually* `Seek` the next `\n`.

Comment: @Darko - reader.BaseStream.Position also gives the entire file length only.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you are using too small files and expect that after reading only one line the reader will move on. That is the wrong assumption.  The BaseStream.Position gets or sets the position within the current stream.

See, the image below, what is written by Microsoft developers.

[image]

Of course, we can create an example. Let's consider the following snippet.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp26
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var fStream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\TEMP\test.xml");
            var reader = new StreamReader(fStream);
            var i = 0;
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {

                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"Line number {i}.Line contents {line}. Reader position is {reader.BaseStream.Position}/{reader.BaseStream.Length}");

            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The content of the file is written below. So, you can easily create the same file on your PC.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<xml>


-<cards>

<name>Majespecter Toad - Ogama</name>

<type>Pendulum Effect Monster</type>

<desc>When this card is Normal or Special Summoned: You can Set 1 "Majespecter" Spell/Trap Card directly from your Deck, but it cannot activate this turn. You can only use this effect of "Majespecter Toad - Ogama" once per turn. Cannot be targeted or destroyed </desc>

<race>Spellcaster</race>

<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/645794.jpg</image_url>

<atk>1300</atk>

<def>500</def>

<level>4</level>

</cards>


-<cards>

<name>Gladiator Beast Retiari</name>

<type>Effect Monster</type>

<desc>When this card is Special Summoned by the effect of a "Gladiator Beast" monster, you can remove from play 1 card from your opponent's Graveyard. At the end of the Battle Phase, if this card attacked or was attacked, you can return it to the Deck to Specia</desc>

<race>Aqua</race>

<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/612115.jpg</image_url>

<atk>1200</atk>

<def>800</def>

<level>3</level>

</cards>


-<cards>

<name>Malefic Rainbow Dragon</name>

<type>Effect Monster</type>

<desc>This card cannot be Normal Summoned or Set. This card cannot be Special Summoned, except by removing from play 1 "Rainbow Dragon" from your hand or Deck. There can only be 1 face-up "Malefic" monster on the field. Other monsters you control cannot declare</desc>

<race>Dragon</race>

<image_url>https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/598988.jpg</image_url>

<atk>4000</atk>

<def>0</def>

<level>10</level>

</cards>

</xml>
```

And how the output looks like, see on the image below. Although, we are reading lines, the position is not changed because the size of the chunk is 1024 bytes. 
[image]